# Accessing bluetooth LE device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have bluetooth LE module rn4020 http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=RN4020 which I successfuly paired and connected to my WP8.1, but I cant find it with following code:

```
private async void ScanDevices()
    {
        lstDevices.Items.Clear();
        string genericUUID = GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids.GenericAccess);

        foreach (DeviceInformation di in await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(genericUUID))
        {
            BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(di.Id);
            lstDevices.Items.Add(new MyBluetoothLEDevice(bleDevice));
        }
    }
```

I have put this addion to manifest:

```
<Capabilities>
<m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile">
  <m2:Device Id="any">
    <m2:Function Type="serviceId:1803" />
  </m2:Device>
</m2:DeviceCapability>
```

Foreach doesnt return any devices. So my question is if someone have idea what I forgot or did wrong (module could also be problem, but I dont think as I paired/connected it without problems).

Answer (score 0):

Without a complete reproducible scenario (which is hard, when half of the equation is your BLE device), it is impossible to know for sure what problems exist in your code. However, the most obvious issue seems to me the specification of the wrong service ID.

In your code, you are searching for `GattServiceUuids.GenericAccess`. That corresponds to the GUID `{00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}`, or the short-form GATT UUID of `0x1800`. But in your manifest, you are specifying `serviceId:1803`.

According to [the Bluetooth documentation](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx?_ga=1.126877517.1736687468.1413936591), the ID of 0x1803 does not even correspond to a known service.

In Windows RT, you can actually [specify the Generic Access profile by name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263090.aspx), as e.g. `<m2:Function Type="name:genericAccess" />`. I don't know whether Windows Phone supports the same, but it's worth a try. Otherwise, you should specify the actual, correct ID of `0x1800`.

Note also that I'm not sure whether Windows Phone allows short IDs in the manifest. If neither `name:genericAccess` nor `serviceId:1800` work, you should specify the full GUID as shown above.

Comment: Thank for response,but I tried all suggestion without success. I will try it in windows RT when I get BLE usb dongle and android phone, to be sure module is working. But I think program should find BLE devices regardless that I put wrong GUID in manifest, only when I would try to read/write to it I would get error.

Comment: _"I think program should find BLE devices regardless that I put wrong GUID in manifest"_ -- you are definitely mistaken about that. Windows uses the manifest to decide which BLE devices and services to expose to the user. In my experience, even when a device/service is listed in the manifest, Windows asks the user if they approve the app accessing the device. A device or service not listed in the manifest is completely invisible to the app.